# How to display Mobile Phone in search results in Sharepoint Online

Tags: search-results

I have a Search Results page that is an employee directory.
Name, work phone, email, department, title all get synced from AD to Azure AD to SPO and display fine, except for mobile phone.

I'm using a Search Results web part with custom display templates.

My question is: when I go under user profiles -> Manage User Profiles -> Select a user -> next to "Mobile phone:", the phone numbers are there (no AD sync icon), because I used the steps in https://www.tishenko.com/sync-mobile-phone-from-aad-to-sharepoint-online/ to sync the mobile phone numbers to SPO from Azure AD. So every user DOES have the Mobile phone data in SPO user profiles. But how do I know that this is what I'm calling in my display template(I'm calling "MobilePhone")? When I go Managed Properties, there's a managed property named "MobilePhone", mapped to "People:CellPhone, ows_CellPhone, ows_Cell_x0020_Phone". How do I know that this "Mobile phone:" field is "People:CellPhone" or "MobilePhone"?

I don't know where the link is.

I'm obviously new to Sharepoint and not even a developer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if you don't have a full solution, please let me know what I need to look up to fill the gap in my understanding. I googled and tried a whole bunch of things to get phone numbers to display, but nothing's working and I think just understanding what is what will be faster than trying inapplicable tricks off internet.

Comment: Figured it out, there was a typo in the display template where a comma was missing in the section where you have the managed property mappings.